# Construction of the Smith Normal Form of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, smith-normal-form

When finding the Smith Normal Form of a given matrix $A$, I do not understand why we can assume $(A_{11})$ is the $\gcd$ of all the entries of the matrix $A$, i.e., how can we generate the $\gcd$ of all the entries (performing elementary columns and row operations) and put it in the position $(1,1)$ of the matrix?

Comment: The Euclidean algorithm lets you calculate a gcd based on quotient calculations, i.e. subtracting numbers from each other. You can do so with rows or columns, thus calculating a gcd of particular entries in the same column/row.

Comment: @ahulpke yes, you're right, but the issue is that once you calculate, let say the $\gcd$ of the first column you made some modifications to the other columns. How can we be sure the $\gcd$ of the new elements in a different column is still the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Euclidean algorithm on rows/columns, first ensure that $A_{11}$ divides all entries $A_{i1}$ in the same column, and then use this to set all $A_{i,1}:=0$ (for $i>1$). Ditto for the row $A_{1i}$. Now suppose there is an entry $A_{ij}$ (for $i,j>1$) that is not divisible by $A_{11}$. Then add the $i$-th row to the first, this keeps $A_{11}$ the same and sets $A_{1j}=A_{ij}$. return to cleaning out row $1$.

Comment: I believe it is important to mention that when applying the Euclidean algorithm to a specific column the modifications made to a different column do not change the $\gcd$ of the elements of that column. To see this, we can think of the Euclidean algorithm as a sequence of subtractions; then notice that when modifying one specific entry, all the entries in that row are "linear combinations" of their respective columns.